# Azure- App services - resourceGroupLocationUndefined error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to create a simple PhP web app services . 
1) I choose the group i have (which is location-less by definition ;)
2) Choose Runtime stack as PHP 7.3
3) Choose the region ( tried different ones e.g. central, east us, europe etc)
4) Choose the monitoring 'Application Insights' with the same region as above. 
On creating the service i get

Code: 'resourceGroupLocationUndefined'. Parameters: ,,.

Comment: how are you trying to do that? with the portal? try incognito mode. also, resource group is not `location-less`. it has a location.

Comment: You are correct. apparently it has a location even though on the main portal it says 'Global' and does not specify a specific location.  I ended up creating a new group for this resource

Comment: resource groups aren't global, do you have a screenshot of that?